# How to access an ApolloServer data source outside of its constructor?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I am using `apollo-datasource-rest` to fetch from a REST API. From the docs, you can integrate a data source like this:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  dataSources: () => ({
    ds1: new Datasource1()
  }),
  resolvers: {
    Post: {
      comments: (post, _args, { dataSources }) => {
        dataSources.ds1.getComments(post.id)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

My issue is that I prefer to use Classes to implement resolvers, so for Post I have something like this:

```
class Post {
  constructor(public id: number, public title: string, public content: string) {}

  comments() {
    return new Datasource1.getComments(this.id)
  }
}
```

I am wondering if this is supported ? 
Can many instances of `Datasource1` share the same cache ? I don't think so.
Is it possible to access `ApolloServer` `dataSources` outside of its constructor ?

Comment: You have access to the `arguments`, `context` and `resolveInfo` in the comments method: `comments(arguments, context, resolveInfo) { context.datasources... }`.

Comment: That is great, I didn't saw it in any doc I went through so far. Thanks man!

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953828/how-to-access-an-apolloserver-data-source-outside-of-its-constructor?noredirect=1#comment104163435_58953828

Comment: I will maybe post an answer here that wraps this in some nicer words :)

Comment: @Herku I may be mistaken here but I'm certain that the first argument to a resolver is not `arguments` but the `rootValue`

Comment: Op talks about resolver objects here. That is the whole point of the question. In resolver objects the root object is `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this came up in a comment again. GraphQL.js allows for two different ways of defining resolvers. Either you work with plain data objects and define resolver logic inside of the schema. This is how most people do GraphQL because this is what most documentations show and what Apollo is preaching. The second way is that you rely on the default resolvers and create data access objects. Let me quickly show how we can imagine a field being resolved conceptionally:

```js
// When the field specifies a resolver
if (typeof fieldConfig.resolver !== 'undefined') {
  return fieldConfig.resolver(root, args, context, resolveInfo);
}
// When the field does not specify a resolver but the root value has a method with
// the same name
if (typeof root[fieldConfig.name] === 'function') {
  return root[fieldConfig.name](args, context, resolveInfo);
}
// Otherwise we return the value under the name with the potential of it being undefined
return root[fieldConfig.name];
```

So we can return objects with methods just like OP is doing for all of our types. The object wraps static properties and has methods for the more complicated fields that require arguments or need access to the context. Notice how in this case the root value is not passed because the method is called *on* the root value. That means that the root value is accessible as `this` inside of the method just as we are used to from OOP.

To answer the question directly: The context is accessible as the second argument in the resolver method. Concretely we can write the following code:

```js
class Post {
  constructor(public id: number, public title: string, public content: string) {}

  comments(_args, { datasources }) {
    return datasources.ds1.getComments(this.id)
  }
}
```